# r dplyr slice which.max not working if group_by has NA

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, max

I noticed that the

```
testdf %>%
  group_by(Column1, Column2, Column3) %>%
  slice(which.max(Column4))
```

`slice(which.max(Column4))` will not work if there are NAs in either Column1 or Column2 or Column3

Wondering if anybody else encountered this problem ? Are there any alternatives to filtering by Max values if `group_by` column has `NA`?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example and your expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? I find the idea of grouping by a column with NAs in quite strange but I would expect it to treat the NAs as a group. Does it not do this?

Comment: @SamR It does this, as shown below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The premise of the question is not generally true:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

# Note: can also use slice_max(col1) instead of slice(which.max(col1))

# Example data: one row with a missing values on col2
df <- tibble(col1 = c(rep(1:5, 2), 3),
             col2 = c(rep(1:2, each = 5), NA),
             col3 = c(rep(1,7), rep(2,4)))

# Group by column with missing value
df %>%
  group_by(col2) %>%
  slice(which.max(col1))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   col2 [3]
#>    col1  col2  col3
#>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     5     1     1
#> 2     5     2     2
#> 3     3    NA     2


# Group by column with missing value and another column
df %>%
  group_by(col2, col3) %>%
  slice(which.max(col1))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   col2, col3 [4]
#>    col1  col2  col3
#>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     5     1     1
#> 2     2     2     1
#> 3     5     2     2
#> 4     3    NA     2
```

Comment: it is a miracle,` slice_max` worked for me but `slice(which.max())` gave me lot of headaches.